# compare android binder's performance with unix-socket

Tags: unix-socket, android-binder

I write a IPC framework using domain socket and protobuf. I compared binder with my IPC Framework  in my x86 ubuntu and anbox on it. [image: Test Result] 
when data size between 8 byte ~ 4K, the performance has no difference.when data size large than 32K, My IPC Framework is better than binder.I think bidner transfer data only copy once,while domain socket copy it two times.How Can I explain the result?(anbox should not bring performance loss)

Comment: Which Binder did you check? The Framework Binder needs to marshall/unmarshall data and the Hardware Binder does not.

Comment: Framework binder I choice, although it need marshall and unmarshall data using parcel, I think the performance should not like this

Answer (score 2):

Binder with `AIDL` will marshall and unmarshal data before copying it. If your IPC does not require that step and copies raw data you have a clear speed benefit. Copying large chunks of data in Android is therefore not typically done via Binder.

If you switch to Hardware Binder with `HIDL` and [Fast Message Queues](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/fmq), things might look a little different. However, you cannot use `HIDL` in the Framework Binder. So this might not be an option for you.